# I have one more day before the end of the month and I have no conversion in Google Ad Grant, what should I do to stay compliant?

Tags: google, google-ads

I have a client that has one more day to get compliant with Google Ad Grants' policy of having at least 1 conversion. What should I do to stay compliant?